# Jira API create issue with 'EPIC NAME"

Tags: jira

I am trying to create an issue and set the Epic Name. 
I know the id of the custom field however it requires an object.

The following is working but it will convert my dict to a string and my Epic Name will be `{"value": "EpicName"}` instead of `EpicName`.

```
    'customfield_100016':
            {
                "value": "EpicName"
            },
```

Anyone has encoutered this issue and could help ?

Comment: How are you create issue? Which library and code you use?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is the problem in your code. Your code is converting your json object into string. Debug your code which is converting this to string.